# no windows phone 7 combo box found

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, combobox

I am using express edition visual studio 2010 for windows phone 7 , 7.1 sdk. I am trying a tutorial over at [app hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Data_Binding_to_Controls#BindingSingleItem) but when i reach the combo example, the combo box doesn't show in the xaml and not even when i run the app.

I looked over in the Toolbox editor in VS and also the combo box isn't there.

Is combo box in the silverlight toolkit? (i don't have it installed, that would justify why i can't see it in the toolbox). If no, why can't i see it? The code in the example (XAML) for the combobox is :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Height="50" Width="400"/>
```

which looks fine to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7 there is a ComboBox, but it is hardly useful. It hasn't been "themed" to the metro style or the Windows Phone 7 guidlines at all. It behaves just like a regular Silverlight control. You could [change the template](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/metro-style-combobox-windows) to a Metro one, or use the `ListPicker` control that is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034). This control overall behaves like other list selectors you'd see in the phone.

Once you've got the toolkit setup and running this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/WP7ListPicker.aspx) article gives a nice walkthrough on how to use it.

Generally, the Silverlight Toolkit is a great asset anyway. There are lots of other out of box controls in there that make things easier. I'd encourage you to review the toolkit's documentation as well.

Comment: as Jon Skeet kindly put it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=VS.95%29.aspx . The link points out that ComboBox is supported in windows phones

Comment: from your link "Actually WP7 has a ComboBox control. Although this control is not directly available from the Visual Studio toolbox (or the Expression Blend 4 for Windows Phone 7 toolbox for that matter), you can add it directly via XAML. It doesn’t look too appealing, especially if you use other Metro-styled controls in your application." . Ok, so we've cleared why the combobox doesn't appear in toolbox, but why is it not working?

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru: It may be present but non-functional, of course.

Comment: I've modified it to point out that "yes, it's there" - but you need to create your own Template for it if you really want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Given the evidence, it sounds like the `ComboBox` class is present, but doesn't actually get rendered properly. It's entirely possible that I ran into this when doing some WP7 development, but that was a year ago :)

Maybe it's *now* both present *and useful* in Windows Phone 7.1, but still not in 7.0...

---

Nope, [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is available in the "stock" Windows Phone 7.0+ SDK:

> **Silverlight for Windows Phone**
>
> Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0

What happens when you try to compile the sample by putting the XAML in directly?

Comment: the weird thing is that if in the xaml i "misspell" ComboBox , the compiler shows an error there. In the xaml i can see only the shape of the combobox but nothign else. when i run the program, the combobox doesn't appear, only the input of the combobox partially appears in a string pattern.

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru: It sounds like it's present for compilation purposes, but doesn't really render :(